Find critical points of the system $\begin{cases} x'=2xy\\ y'=1-x^2+y^2 \end{cases}$

Find critical points of the system
$$\begin{cases}
x'=2xy\\ 
y'=1-x^2+y^2
\end{cases}$$
and show that linvarization does not help to establish their properties. Using the Phase portrait method, show that both critical points are centers

It is easy to see that the critical points of the system are $(1,0)$ and $(-1,0)$. Let's find the Jacobian of the system
$$J = \begin{pmatrix}
\frac{\partial x'}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial x'}{\partial y} \\
\frac{\partial y'}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial y'}{\partial y}
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
2y & 2x \\
-2x & 2y
\end{pmatrix}$$
Let us substitute the critical points into the Jacobian of the system
$$J(1, 0) = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 2 \\
-2 & 0
\end{pmatrix}\Rightarrow \det\begin{pmatrix}
- \lambda & 2 \\
-2 & - \lambda
\end{pmatrix} = \lambda^2 + 4 = 0 \Rightarrow  \lambda = \pm 2i$$
$$J(-1, 0) = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & -2 \\
2 & 0
\end{pmatrix}\Rightarrow \det\begin{pmatrix}
- \lambda & -2 \\
2 & - \lambda
\end{pmatrix} = \lambda^2 + 4 = 0 \Rightarrow  \lambda = \pm 2i$$
The problem is that both critical points have imaginary eigenvalues, which makes it impossible to determine the stability of these points and I cannot show that both critical points are centers. Is there another approach to prove that both critical points are centers?

Making $z = x + iy$ we have $z'=i(1-z^2)$

$$\begin{cases}
x=r\cos \varphi \\ 
y=r\sin \varphi 
\end{cases}\Rightarrow \begin{cases}
\dot{r}\cos \varphi -r\dot{\varphi }\sin \varphi =r^2\sin 2\varphi \\ 
\dot{r}\sin \varphi +r\dot{\varphi }\cos \varphi =1-r^2\cos2\varphi 
\end{cases}\Leftrightarrow$$
$$\Leftrightarrow \dot{r}\begin{bmatrix}
\cos \varphi \\
\sin \varphi 
\end{bmatrix}+r\dot{\varphi }\begin{bmatrix}
-\sin \varphi \\ 
\cos \varphi 
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
\cos \varphi  & -\sin \varphi \\ 
 \sin \varphi &\cos \varphi  
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
\dot{r}\\
r\dot{\varphi }
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
r^2\sin 2\varphi \\ 
1-r^2\cos 2\varphi 
\end{bmatrix}$$
$$\begin{vmatrix}
\cos \varphi  &-\sin \varphi  \\ 
 \sin \varphi & \cos \varphi 
\end{vmatrix}=\cos^2\varphi +\sin^2\varphi =1\neq 0\Rightarrow$$
$$\Rightarrow \begin{bmatrix}
\dot{r}\\ 
r\dot{\varphi }
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
\cos \varphi  &-\sin \varphi  \\ 
 \sin \varphi &\cos \varphi  
\end{bmatrix}^{-1}\begin{bmatrix}
r^2\sin 2\varphi \\ 
1-r^2\cos 2\varphi 
\end{bmatrix}=$$
$$=\begin{bmatrix}
\cos \varphi  &\sin \varphi  \\ 
 -\sin \varphi &\cos \varphi  
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
r^2\sin 2\varphi  \\ 
1-r^2\cos 2\varphi 
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
\left ( 1+r^2 \right )\sin \varphi \\ 
\left ( 1-r^2 \right )\cos \varphi 
\end{bmatrix}\Rightarrow \frac{\mathrm{d} r}{r\mathrm{d} \varphi }=\frac{1+r^2}{1-r^2}\tan \varphi \Rightarrow $$
$$\Rightarrow \int\limits_{r_0}^{r}\frac{\left ( 1-\rho ^2 \right )}{\rho \left ( 1+\rho ^2 \right )}d\rho =\frac{1}{2}\int\limits_{r_0^2}^{r^2}\frac{(1-\sigma )}{\sigma (1+\sigma )}d\sigma =\frac{1}{2}\int\limits_{r_0^2}^{r^2}\left ( \frac{1}{\sigma }-\frac{2}{1+\sigma } \right )d\sigma =\ln \frac{r}{1+r^2}-\ln\frac{r_0}{1+r_0^2}=$$
$$=\int\limits_{\varphi _0}^{\varphi }\tan \theta d\theta =\ln \cos \varphi_0-\ln \cos \varphi \Rightarrow \frac{x}{1+x^2+y^2}=\frac{x_0}{1+x_0^2+y_0^2}=a$$
$$F(x;y;a)=\left ( x-\frac{1}{2a} \right )^2+y^2=\frac{1-4a^2}{4a^2}\geq 0\Rightarrow -\frac{1}{2}\leq a\leq \frac{1}{2}$$
$$ F\left ( x;y;\pm \frac{1}{2} \right )=\left ( x\mp 1 \right )^2+y^2=0$$
